# XSLV web part: default xsl templates

Tags: xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part

Where default xsl templates for xslt view list web part are soterd? 
As I know I can override any template in custom XSL file, but where can I find all the default templates? For example I need a template with mode=PrintFieldWithECB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open a page using a default XSLV in SharePoint Designer you will see that it uses `GhostedXslLink="main.xsl"` and I believe this is the file found in *\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\XSL*.

Comment: Thank you so much! There are serveral files there with templates. And PrintFieldWithECB is in file fldtypes.xsl